# subtract 2 days from a date which is in m-d-Y H:i:s format in PHP

Tags: php, date, datetime

I get the current date using this code :

```
$currentdate= date('m-d-Y H:i:s');

echo $currentdate; // prints 06-22-2019 11:02:49
```

To subtract two days from the current date I use this code :

```
 $date = date('m-d-Y H:i:s ', strtotime('-2 days', strtotime($currentdate)));
 echo $date; // print's 12-30-1969 01:00:00
```

**The expected output is 06-20-2019 11:02:49** //basic requirement is just that the date should be current date - 2 days.
What I'm I doing wrong here? This code works perfectly if the dates are in Y-m-d H:i:s format.

Comment: strtotime understands m/d/Y  and d-m-Y

Comment: Because `m-d-Y` is not supported by `strtotime`.

Comment: ok thanks for the suggestion. So how can I achieve the expected output in this case?

Comment: replace '-' by '/'

Comment: perfect. this works. Now I'll replace / from the output with -

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$currentdate= date('m-d-Y H:i:s');
echo $currentdate; //gives 06-22-2019 14:58:55


$date = date('m-d-Y H:i:s ', strtotime('-2 days', strtotime(date('Y-m-d H:i:s'))));
echo $date;  //gives 06-20-2019 14:58:55
```

Answer (score 1):

Check php datetime format there is no `m "-" d "-" y` format.

[image]

But you can Use `M "-" d "-" y` or `M "-" d "-" Y`

[Check live Example](https://eval.in/1117242)

[Check More on Official Link](https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.date.php)

Answer (score 0):

So as per the suggestions from the comments on this question I was able to get the output using this code by replacing `-` with `/` :

```
$currentdate= date('m/d/Y H:i:s'); //prints 06/22/2019 11:26:05
$date = date('m/d/Y H:i:s ', strtotime('-2 days', strtotime($currentdate)));
echo str_replace('/', '-', $date);   //prints 06-20-2019 11:20:50 which is the desired output
```

Comment: You can still show date with your template `m-d-Y H:i:s`. just `strtotime('-2 days', strtotime(str_replace('-', '/', $currentdate))));`